# Allow user to add marker to google maps only at specific zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a website where users will be allowed to add their properties on google map using markers/pins, I want to (Obligate) the user to go to the max allowed zoom level to be able to set the pin/marker, so as to have a specific exact location of the property.

Comment: and the question is  ???

Comment: How to ONLY show the marker at a specific zoom, and show a msg (Please zoom in to the property location) once he/she click on any wider zoom ?

Comment: What does your existing code look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Check the [MaxZoomService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`getZoom()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/map#Map.getZoom) method on the `Map` object and check what the current zoom level is before allowing a new `Marker` to be created.

Here's a [simple sample JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bixedaruni/edit?html,output) adapted from the [Remove Markers sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) from Google's documentation. The pertinent code:

```
// Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
  if (map.getZoom() < 17) {
    alert('please zoom in closer to add a new marker');
  } else {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why `17`? Is that the maximum zoom level? Everywhere?